# ServiceStack Server Sent Events behind an Apache

Tags: apache, servicestack, server-sent-events

We have enabled the ServerEventsFeaures plugin and is working just fine.
However on client site they have an apache server that acts as a reverse proxy and produces errors when the server sends the event-heartbeat event.
The client site is http://clientserver/services. So in the httpd-proxy.conf we added the entries

ProxyPass /theservices http://clientserver:81/theservices

ProxyPassreverse /theservices http://clientserver:81/theservices

The event-stream works ok and calls http://clientserver/theservices/event-stream, but the event-hearbeat comes as http://clientserver:81/theservices/event-heartbeat with the response header
HTTP/1.1 403 Invalid User Address

We noticed that despite this, 90% of the messages are successfully delivered to the users, but some are not.

Any ideas on how can we fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove end-user IP Address Validation with:

```
Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature {
    ValidateUserAddress = false
});
```